# SQL SUM() function field

Tags: mysql, database-design, function, sum

I have a database which contains some numerical fields; now i want to create another field which displays the sum of one of these fields. How can I create that field?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUM() leads to believe that you're talking about
aggregate functions.

However, I think, in order for your question to make sense,
you are *really* talking about summing a few values
within one record. This assumption migth be wrong, if
not, then you might try:

```
create view vw 
 as select 
   col_1, col_2, col_3, 
   col_1 + col_2 + col_3 as col_sum
from tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD SumColumn AS Column 1 + Column2 + Column3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up another field which is the result of of a function which calculates the sum sum() function, but this will have performance implications.  A better solution maybe to set up a trigger which calculates the sum on insert or update of one of the other fields and then inserts it to the sum field

Comment: i have a column which contains about 100 numerical values;
i only want the sum of these values into an index or a new field

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the derived value in a view and select from that?